# running rosjava_tutorial_pubsub

Tags: rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have successfully built the tutorial, but I don't know how to get it running. I will be grateful for any help.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11179/running-rosjava_tutorial_pubsub/) by [chcorbato](https://answers.ros.org/users/305/chcorbato/) on ROS Answers with karma: 202 on 2011-09-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To run a rosjava node do:

```
# rosrun rosjava_bootstrap run.py <PACKAGE> <Node>
```

for example for the tutorial:

```
# rosrun rosjava_bootstrap run.py rosjava_tutorial_pubsub org.ros.tutorials.pubsub.Talker
```

to run the talker,

and in another terminal:

```
# rosrun rosjava_bootstrap run.py rosjava_tutorial_pubsub org.ros.tutorials.pubsub.Listener
```

For me it only works once I've previously launched the ros Master, seems that it fails when launching it from the java Classes of the nodes

---

Originally posted by [chcorbato](https://answers.ros.org/users/305/chcorbato/) with karma: 202 on 2011-09-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1